# Absolute and relative positioning in menu

Tags: html, css

We all have hard times with positioning absolute divs :S
In my case its horizontal sub-menus with this css:

```
ul.children{
display:none;
position:absolute;
}
ul.children li{
position:relative;
height:60px;
float:none;
}
li.page_item_has_children:hover > ul.children{
display:inline;
}
```

[image]

As you can see on the picture whole submenu moves to the left for 50% of the parents width...
I tried everything and created just a bigger mess xD

So if anyone can help me out with this I will be very thankful :)

HTML:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2 page_item_has_children">
    <a href="url">About</a>
    <ul class='children'>
        <li class="page_item page-item-39">
            <a href="url">About</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-41">
            <a href="url">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

I can't change html cause its wordpress theme :S

Comment: Could you post some html?

Comment: *"We all have hard times with positioning absolute divs :S I"* - No we don't.  ;)

Comment: @Morsus Do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/10pxegb1/

Comment: I was thinking about adding margin-left:-xx px; but not all divs have same width so on some would be ok and on some would be moved again.

Comment: @GolezTrol I was thinking about us beginners :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.page_item_has_children {
  position: relative;
}

ul.children {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 200px; /* or whatever makes sense */
}

ul.children li {
  height: 60px;
}

.page_item_has_children:hover > ul.children {
  display: block;
}
```

The important piece here is to make sure the 'page_item_has_children' element is relatively positioned and that the child 'ul' is absolutely positioned.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erier/z047bdn8/2/)

Comment: This is the closest answer to what i want. Still have some issues when child text is longer than parents..

Comment: You're right. In that case, you'll need to just figure out what makes sense for a 'min-width' of 'ul.children'. 'ul.children' will be the same width as it's parent _unless_ you define a min-width. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erier/z047bdn8/2/)

Comment: Just to be thorough, it doesn't _have_ to be **'min-width'**. You could just use **'width'** as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

```css
ul.children {
  display: none;
}

ul.children li {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  float: none;
}

li.page_item_has_children:hover > ul.children {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="page_item page-item-2 page_item_has_children">
    <a href="url">About</a>
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="page_item page-item-39">
        <a href="url">About</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-41">
        <a href="url">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="page_item page-item-2 page_item_has_children">
    <a href="url">More info</a>
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="page_item page-item-39">
        <a href="url">Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-41">
        <a href="url">Item 2</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-41">
        <a href="url">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that,if i remove absolute position it stretches the parent's div's width and moves all menu items to right.

Comment: See my update.  Hard to know what's causing your problem without seeing more code.  Looks like @erier is pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: I see the problem.  Add this style to prevent wrapping of links:  `a {white-space: nowrap;}`

Comment: Oh that solved it,I just added that style to my ".menu li a"  class. Thank you. :)

Comment: Good call with 'white-space', @RickHitchcock